# wchar_t* with UTF8 chars in MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++, utf-8, wchar-t

I am trying to format `wchar_t*` with UTF-8 characters using `vsnprintf` and then printing the buffer using `printf`.

Given the following code:

```
/*
  This code is modified version of KB sample:
  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rtref/vsnprintf.htm

  The usage of `setlocale` is required by my real-world scenario,
  but can be modified if that fixes the issue.
*/

#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

#ifdef MSVC
#include <windows.h>
#endif

void vout(char *string, char *fmt, ...)
{
   setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
   va_list arg_ptr;

   va_start(arg_ptr, fmt);
   vsnprintf(string, 100, fmt, arg_ptr);
   va_end(arg_ptr);
}

int main(void)
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
#ifdef MSVC
   SetConsoleOutputCP(65001); // with or without; no dice
#endif

   char string[100];

   wchar_t arr[] = { 0x0119 };
   vout(string, "%ls", arr);
   printf("This string should have 'ę' (e with ogonek / tail) after colon:  %s\n", string);
   return 0;
}
```

I compiled with gcc v5.4 on Ubuntu 16 to get the desired output in BASH:

```
gcc test.c -o test_vsn
./test_vsn
This string should have 'ę' (e with ogonek / tail) after colon:  ę
```

However, on Windows 10 with CL v19.10.25019 (VS 2017), I get weird output in CMD:

```
cl test.c /Fetest_vsn /utf-8
.\test_vsn
This string should have 'T' (e with ogonek / tail) after colon:  e
```

(the `ę` before colon becomes `T` and after the colon is `e` without ogonek)

Note that I used CL's new `/utf-8` switch (introduced in VS 2015), which apparently has no effect with or without. Based on their [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/22/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/):

> There is also a /utf-8 option that is a synonym for setting “/source-charset:utf-8” and “/execution-charset:utf-8”.

(my source file already has BOM / utf8'ness and execution-charset is apparently not helping)

What could be the minimal amount of changes to the code / compiler switches to make the output look identical to that of gcc?

Comment: On Windows, `printf()` (and the console in general) does not support UTF-8. You could use `WideCharToMultiByte()` (or equivalent) to convert UTF-16 encoded `wchar_t` data to UTF-8, but that is still no guarantee the console will display it correctly. You really should be writing Unicode data to the console using Unicode console APIs, like the Win32 `WriteConsoleW()` function, or `std::wcout` in C++. There are plenty of questions on StackOverflow on how to output Unicode data to a Windows console. Your reputation is high enough that you should have known to do some research before asking.

Comment: You can also run the PowerShell IDE and navigate to your program's directory, then run your program.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks. I will give `WideCharToMultiByte()` and other Unicode console APIs a try. I did some research but got lost in product versioning (e.g. since VS2015, the inclusion of vsnprintf OOTB etc.). Will read some more. :)

Comment: @ChronoKitsune, the same executable outputs `This string should have 'ÄT' (e with ogonek / tail) after colon:  e` in PS.

Comment: @vulcanraven: If you write to the console using Unicode APIs, you *don't* need to use `WideCharToMultiByte()` to convert your Unicode data to another encoding.  Unicode APIs on Windows take `wchar_t` data as input.

Comment: @vulcanraven: this is the kind of situation where you should wrap your logging code in a custom function that takes Unicode strings as input and then writes them to the console according to the needs of the underlying platform - as UTF-8 on Ubunto, as UTF-16 on Windows, etc.

Comment: If the locale setting appears wrong the first thing to check is the return value of `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");`  Was that `NULL`?  
"If the selection cannot be honored, the setlocale function returns a null pointer and the program’s locale is not changed."

Comment: @RemyLebeau The lack of support with "On Windows, printf() (...) does not support UTF-8." is a compiler issue, not an OS issue.

Comment: @chux: `printf` is a C runtime function, not a compiler function, but either way it ultimately calls platform APIs for the actual output, and the console APIs on Windows simply do not support UTF-8

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hmm, `int main() {
  printf("%p\n", setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8"));
  putwchar(0x0119);
  puts("");
}` prints `0x1801fca20
ę` on my windows machine `cmd.exe` console.  Certainly looks like UTF-8 support.

Comment: @chux: that does not prove UTF-8 is being used. `putwchar()` takes a `wchar_t` as input and is simply required to write it to the console, it very well could be using Microsoft's `wchar_t` based console API, which would be natural on Windows, no conversion to UTF-8 needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Fair point.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I re-direct the program's output to a file with `foo > t` and then dumped the file's 15-byte contents: `30 78 31 38 30 31 66 63 61 32 30 0a c4 99 0a`  The `c4 99` is certainly [UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0119/index.htm) for LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH OGONEK

Answer (score 0):

Based on @RemyLebeau's comment, I modified the code to use `w` variant of the printf APIs to get the output identical with msvc on Windows, matching that of gcc on Unix.

Additionally, instead of changing codepage, I have now used [`_setmode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode) (`FILE` translation mode).

```
/*
  This code is modified version of KB sample:
  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rtref/vsnprintf.htm

  The usage of `setlocale` is required by my real-world scenario,
  but can be modified if that fixes the issue.
*/

#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <io.h> //for _setmode
#include <fcntl.h> //for _O_U16TEXT
#endif

void vout(wchar_t *string, wchar_t *fmt, ...)
{
   setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
   va_list arg_ptr;

   va_start(arg_ptr, fmt);
   vswprintf(string, 100, fmt, arg_ptr);
   va_end(arg_ptr);
}

int main(void)
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
#ifdef _WIN32
   int oldmode = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
#endif

   wchar_t string[100];

   wchar_t arr[] = { 0x0119, L'\0' };
   vout(string, L"%ls", arr);
   wprintf(L"This string should have 'ę' (e with ogonek / tail) after colon:  %ls\r\n", string);

#ifdef _WIN32
   _setmode(_fileno(stdout), oldmode);
#endif
   return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, we can use `fwprintf` and provide `stdout` as first argument. To do the same with `fwprintf(stderr,format,args)` (or `perror(format, args)`), we would need to `_setmode` the `stderr` as well.