# Display content of UTF-8 byte array?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode

I have an array of approximately 400 UTF-8 bytes.  How can I display the corresponding text?  It almost certainly contains several emojis, along with ASCII.

Platform is Windows with Visual C++, but I can switch to macOS or Linux if necessary.  Happy to use a 3rd party library too.

*Clarification: It's a console application, so I'd like to display the result in a console.  I can use Windows Terminal instead.  Looks like `MultiByteToWideChar` is what I need.*

Comment: "*display*" how/where exactly? Outside the console it's platform dependent, and inside the console it can be tricky on most platforms.

Comment: Write to a utf-8 compatible output device, e.g. [windows terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal). It's not really a C++ question unless you are contemplating rendering fonts yourself or something?

Comment: Display it where? Since I don't know the details you could convert the `UTF8` to `UTF16` using `MultiByteToWideChar` and then use `std::wcout` or some Win32 `W` function to do whatever it is you're trying to do

Comment: A Windows console can't really display Unicode using the stdio interface.  You'll need to call some specific Windows API functions for the console.

Comment: @MarkRansom The Windows console can technically display Unicode via the standard streams, though it takes some hoops. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45461313) for example to another question [wchar_t* with UTF8 chars in MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449346/wchar-t-with-utf8-chars-in-msvc).

Comment: As @M.M pointed out, he could use the `Windows Terminal` instead and just display the `UTF8` as is. That of course is assuming that he needs this for personal reasons ie not depending on a client having the `Windows Terminal` installed.

Comment: regarding the "Clarification", if you use Windows Terminal then you do NOT use multibytetowidechar , since that terminal can display UTF-8